# Error while implementing hello world system call in Lunix

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, system-calls

I am compiling my kernel for my hello world system call but getting following error:

*ld: arch/x86/entry/syscall_64.o:(.rodata+0xdc0): undefined reference to `__x64_sys_hello' ld: arch/x86/entry/syscall_x32.o:(.rodata+0xdc0): undefined reference to` __x64_sys_hello' make: *** [Makefile:1139: vmlinux] Error 1 site:stackoverflow.com*

Following are the changes i made to add my hello world system call:

**Current kernel version=5.11.0.40**

**linux-5.8.1/hello/hello.c:**

```
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/syscalls.h>

asmlinkage long sys_hello(void)
{
        printk("Hello world\n");
        return 0;
}
```

**linux-5.8.1/Makefile:**

```
ifeq ($(KBUILD_EXTMOD),)
core-y        += kernel/ certs/ mm/ fs/ ipc/ security/ crypto/ block/ hello/
```

**linux-5.8.1/include/linux$ gedit syscalls.h**

```
asmlinkage long sys_hello(void);
```

**linux-5.8.1/arch/x86/entry/syscalls$ gedit syscall_64.tbl**

```
440    common    hello            sys_hello
```

Looking forward for your responses.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This code:

```
asmlinkage long sys_hello(void)
{
        printk("Hello world\n");
        return 0;
}
```

needs to be changed to:

```
SYSCALL_DEFINE0(hello)
{
        printk("Hello world\n");
        return 0;
}
```

The `SYSCALL_DEFINE0(sname)` macro is defined by `#include <linux/syscalls.h>`.  It is defined differently depending on whether `CONFIG_ARCH_HAS_SYSCALL_WRAPPER` is defined in the kernel config.  It is defined for some architectures, but not for others.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response.It worked.