# Adding syscall in Kernel for Raspberry Pi 4

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, system-calls, raspberry-pi4

I am trying to add syscalls to Rpi4 for the latest kernel version 5.x.
I can't find a proper guide to do so since there are lots of changes between version 4 and 5.
Can anybody point me in the right direction to get started with just a simple syscall like hello world.

Thank you.

Comment: Actually, when talk about adding a system call. nothing has been changed in kernel 4.x and 5.x. The same syscall tables are needed to be modified, the same SYSCALL_DEFINE macro is needed to be used. You could follow e.g. [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70223135/error-while-implementing-hello-world-system-call-in-lunix) and its answer.

Comment: Also nothing specific ro RPi

Comment: But i am confused with what syscall_table to use for RPI since it is ARM architecture.

Comment: I think the same syscalls are used for RPi. [Look](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromiumos/docs/+/master/constants/syscalls.md#arm64-64_bit)